# Analyse the US presidential election from the perspective of Arrow's theory

Tags: economics, decision-theory, voting-theory

I want to consider the voting system against the 4 Arrow's axioms.

So first the voting system simplifies to first-past-the post system where the highest polling candidate wins the election.

How does this fit in with the 4 axioms?

> Unrestricted domain

A full ordering is provided given by the number of votes for each candidate

> No dictator

There is no individual whose votes decide the final result - everyone's vote matters.

> Pareto

If everybody prefers candidate $y$ to $x$ then so will the group, because $y$ will receive more votes

> Independence of irrelevant alternatives

What is the effect of removing candidate $X$ on the preference between $Y$ and $Z$? This will have no effect because if $Y$ has more votes than $Z$ then this will remain the case even if $X$ is removed.

---

By my working, all $4$ axioms are fulfilled but this contradicts Arrow's Impossibility Theorem: there is no social welfare function meeting all $4$ above conditions.

**Where have I gone wrong?**

Perhaps Pareto needs to be reconsidered. This is *"If each individual has $x>_iy$ then the group has $x>_gy$"*

But I suppose the group preference is there is just one candidate who is better than them all. So say if candidate $A$ wins, $B$ has the second most votes and $C$ has the third most votes. Every individual has $B$ is preferred to $C$ but this is not reflected by the group.

Would really appreciate some input on this.

**Edit: My interpretation of the 4th condition was incorrect, please see the below answer**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Independence of irrelevant alternatives fails. Your conclusion that removing $X$ will have no effect on the preference between $Y$ and $Z$ is wrong. If one person has preference $Z\gt Y\gt X$ and everyone else has preference $X\gt Y\gt Z$, then $Z$ is socially preferred to $Y$ if $X$ is in the race, whereas otherwise $Y$ is socially preferred to $Z$. (I'm assuming that by "votes" you meant "first preferences".)

Comment: Oh ok, so the fact that people have only one 'best' option is important. If we has 3 voters and 3 candidates, $X, Y$ and $Z$. Voter 1's preference: $Z>Y>X$. Voter 2 and 3's preference: $X>Y>Z$ . This leads to group preference $X>Z>Y$, going by first preferences. If $X$ were removed we get Voter 1's preference: $Z>Y$ and Voter 2 and 3's preference: $Y>Z$... this leads to $Y>Z$ so removing $X$ changes the group preference between $Y$ and $Z$